# How to write text to empty bookmark value which is under text form field using openxml

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I would like to insert/write text to book mark which is under text form field of the existing Microsoft word using c#.  Default value of bookmark is Null. If I use below line of code with the help of openxml, I can insert text to book mark place but it is added as normal text and not in text form field.

```
         using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filePath, true))
            {
                // Access the main document part
                MainDocumentPart mainPart = doc.MainDocumentPart;

                // Access the document content
                Document document = mainPart.Document;

                BookmarkStart bookmarkStart = document.Descendants<BookmarkStart>() .FirstOrDefault(b => b.Name == "bookMarkName");

                if (bookmarkStart != null)
                {
                    BookmarkEnd bookmarkEnd = bookmarkStart.NextSibling<BookmarkEnd>();
                    Paragraph parentBookmark = bookmarkStart.Parent as Paragraph;

                    // Clear the existing content of the bookmark

                    OpenXmlElement nextElement = bookmarkStart.NextSibling();
                     while (nextElement != null && nextElement != bookmarkEnd)
                     {
                         OpenXmlElement sibling = nextElement.NextSibling();
                         nextElement.Remove();
                         nextElement = sibling;
                     }
                    Run newRun = new Run(new Text("Your new text goes here"));
                    parentBookmark.InsertAfter(newRun, bookmarkStart);

                    doc.Save();
                }
           }
```

I tried to find two ways.

1. How to update the default text of text form field using openxml ?

2. After adding plain text to bookmark, I find how to add bookmark to that plain text. But I couldn't find solution on online. I hope someone can help me. Thank you in advance.

Below image is the result that I want to achieve. I would like to insert text "hello" under bookmark name="test" .

.[image: The result I would like to achieve]

Comment: The following may (or may not) be helpful. Create the Word document as desired using Word. Then download/install the [Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool](https://github.com/dotnet/Open-XML-SDK/releases/tag/v2.5). Open the Word document using the _Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool_. Then click _Reflect Code_. You'll be able to see how the document is represented in Open XML which should be beneficial when attempting to create/modify the code programmatically.

Comment: The bookmark should be a part of the formfield, not underlying it. It is an attribute of the field.

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply. I have used [open XML SDK Productivity Tool](https://github.com/dotnet/Open-XML-SDK/releases/tag/v2.5) and checked on "Reflect Code". But I still don't know how to modify the code programmatically. Can you show me with example code? @Tudeschizieuinchid

Comment: Yes, the bookmark is the attribute of the field. @CharlesKenyon